# Giving grails configuration options in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'd like to set up tomcat to run two instances of the same grail project (WAR-file, will be put in different directories and available under different host-entries) which need to have different configurations.

In the grails command line I can just use -Dparam=value to set an configuration option (this is used to give the path to a configuration file). How can I do this in a tomcat container/host?

At the moment I have set this option for tomcat under /etc/default/tomcat7 - but this does not make it possible to use different configuration entries for different tomcat hosts.
I tried to use

```
<Host ...>
    <Context path="" appBase="/a/b/c">
         <Environment name="APPNAME_CONFIG" value="/path/to/config/file" type="java.lang.String" />
    </Context>
</Host>
```

but this does not work.

How can I give such a configuration option for a tomcat host?

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat documentation says that you can use JNDI Context to read the environment entries. So the following should work.

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
def envCtx = initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/APPNAME_CONFIG");
```

Comment: I know that. It works well using grails command line. But I now want to do it with tomcat and a war-file.